# Finding the value of $6b-3a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Consider $f(x)= [x]^2 - [x+6]$ and $g(x)= 3kx^2+ 2x + 4(1-3k)$ where
>   $[x]$ denotes the floor function.
>
> Let $A= \{x ~|~ f(x)= 0\}$ and $k \in [a,b]$ for which every element
>   of set A satisfies the inequality $g(x)\ge 0$.
>
> 1) The set $A$ is equal to ?
>
> 2) The value of $6b- 3a =$?

The first part is easy. It's just the solution of the quadratic; $[x]^2- [x]- 6 = 0 $

$\therefore \mathbb A = [-2, -1) \cup [3,4)$ which is the right answer.

But I am stuck on the second part of the question.  I am unable to use the constraint on the values of $x$ to find k.

using the condition I have got:

$k(12- 3x^2) \ge -{2(x+2)} $

For $x=2$ this is true, 
 For $x\ne 2$:

$\implies3k(2-x) \ge -2 $

What do I do next?

The answer is :

> $2$

Comment: I obtain:
$$g(x)=k(3x^2-12)+2(x+2)$$
so $g(x) \geq 0$ is the same as:
$$k(3x^2-12) \geq -2(x+2)$$. Are you sure of your condition ?

Answer (score 1):

You need for $k$ to satify:
$$k (3x^2-12) =3k(x-2)(x+2)\geq -2(x+2)$$ for all $x \in \Bbb A= [-2, -1) \cup [3,4)$.

You can then consider the three cases:

- $x=-2$ then the inequality is verified.
- For all $x \in (-2, -1)$, as $x-2 <0$ and $x+2>0$ the inequality is equivalent to:
  $$k \leq \frac{2}{3(2-x)}$$
  and as it must be true for any $x$ and $\inf_{x \in(-2,-1)} \frac{2}{3(2-x)}=\frac{2}{3(2-(-2))}=\frac{1}{6}$ it is the same as:
  $$k \leq \frac{1}{6}$$
- For all $x \in (3, 4)$, as $x-2 >0$ and $2+x>0$ the inequality is equivalent to:
  $$k \geq -\frac{2}{3(x-2)}$$
  and once again as $\sup_{x \in(3,4)} \frac{-2}{3(x-2)}= \frac{-2}{3(4-2)}=\frac{-1}{3}$ it is true iff:
  $$k \geq -\frac{1}{3}$$

Thus $g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \{-2\} \cup (-2, -1) \cup [3,4)$ iff:
$$-\frac{1}{3} \leq k \leq \frac{1}{6}$$
i.e:

$$a=-\frac{1}{3}$$

$$b=\frac{1}{6}$$
and:
$$6b-3a=1-(-1)=2$$